# Keep on Calculating in Calculator

Tags: .net, vb.net, calculator

I'm making an simple calculator in VB.Net

I am expanding the code, cause i want it that way that if you make like this operation

```
input(8) input(+) input(2) input(=) result(10)
```

but then if I press like the divide button and an other number I would like to have it this way:

```
 previousResult(10) input(/) input(5) input(=) newResult(2)
```

Also if i keep making calculations without pressing the equal operator from time to time
It should also give an correct value

```
input(8) input(+) input(2) input(/) input(2) input(+) input(5) input(=) result(10)
```

It should always keep on going no matter how many times calculate an new operation.
And it should always keep on going no matter what operator I click (+,-,/,*)

I have already made some many variables and functions that the whole thing is a mess.
My first calculation will work with case +

But then with an other case + the result is wrong...here is my code:

```
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off
Option Explicit On


    Public Class SimpleCalculatorForm

    #Region "FormLoad"

    Private Sub SimpleCalculatorForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim decimalSeperator As Char = Convert.ToChar(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)
        DecimalSeperatorButton.Text = decimalSeperator

        ResultTextbox.Text = "0"
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "Methods"


    Private Sub RemoveMinusBeforeValue()
        For Each letter As String In ResultTextbox.Text
            Dim pos As Integer = pos + 1
            If letter = "-" Then
                ResultTextbox.Text = ResultTextbox.Text.Substring(pos, ResultTextbox.Text.Length - pos)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Function ThereIsAnValue() As Boolean
        Dim x As Boolean
        For Each number As String In ResultTextbox.Text
            If number <> "0" Then
                x = True
                Exit For
            Else : x = False
            End If
        Next
        Return x
    End Function
    Public Function TextboxContainsDecimalSeparator() As Boolean
        Dim x As Boolean
        For Each letter As String In ResultTextbox.Text
            If letter = "," Then
                x = True
                Exit For
            Else : x = False
            End If
        Next
        Return x
    End Function
    Public Function TheValueIsPositive() As Boolean
        Dim x As Boolean
        For Each letter As String In ResultTextbox.Text
            If letter = "-" Then
                x = False
                Exit For
            Else : x = True
            End If
        Next

        Return x
    End Function

    Public Sub ContainsZero(number As String)
        If ResultTextbox.Text = "0" OrElse ResultTextbox.Text = "-0" Then
            ResultTextbox.Text = number
        ElseIf ResultTextbox.Text = "0.0" AndAlso number = "0" Then
            ResultTextbox.Text = number

        Else : ResultTextbox.Text &= number
        End If
    End Sub

#End Region


#Region "NumericButtons"

    Private Sub Numeric_Buttons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ZeroButton.Click, OneButton.Click, TwoButton.Click, ThreeButton.Click, _
                                                                            FourButton.Click, FiveButton.Click, SixButton.Click, SevenButton.Click, _
                                                                                EightButton.Click, NineButton.Click

        Dim x As Button = CType(sender, Button)
        Dim button As String = x.Text
        ContainsZero(button)

        If _Calculatevalue1 = Nothing Then
            _Calculatevalue1 &= button
        Else
            _Calculatevalue2 &= button
        End If


    End Sub



    Private Sub DecimalSeperatorButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DecimalSeperatorButton.Click
        Dim x As Button = CType(sender, Button)
        Dim button As String = x.Text

        If TextboxContainsDecimalSeparator() = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("You cannot enter 2 times the ',' sign")
        Else : ResultTextbox.Text &= button
        End If


    End Sub

#End Region


#Region "OperatorButtons"


    Private Sub ClearButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClearButton.Click

        If ResultTextbox.Text = "0" Then
            MessageBox.Show("The field is already empty")
        ElseIf ResultTextbox.Text <> "0" Then
            ResultTextbox.Text = "0"
            _Calculatevalue1 = Nothing
            _Calculatevalue2 = Nothing
            _Calculatevalue3 = Nothing



        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub NegationButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NegationButton.Click

        If TheValueIsPositive() Then
            ResultTextbox.Text = "-" & ResultTextbox.Text
            _Calculatevalue3 = ResultTextbox.Text
        Else : RemoveMinusBeforeValue()
            _Calculatevalue3 = ResultTextbox.Text

        End If
    End Sub

    Private _Calculatevalue1 As String
    Private _Calculatevalue2 As String
    Private _TheFinalResult As Decimal
    Private _CurrentOperator As String
    Private _Calculatevalue3 As String


    Private Sub Operators_Buttons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AdditionButton.Click, SubtractionButton.Click, _
                                                                                MultiplicationButton.Click, DivisionButton.Click
        Dim x As Button = CType(sender, Button)
        Dim button As String = x.Text

        _CurrentOperator = button



        If _Calculatevalue1 = Nothing AndAlso ThereIsAnValue() = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Give in a value before u use an operator")


            ResultTextbox.Text = "0"

        Else
            If ThereIsAnValue() Then

                If _Calculatevalue3 = Nothing Then
                    Select Case button

                        Case "+"
                            _Calculatevalue3 = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDecimal(_Calculatevalue1) + Convert.ToDecimal(_Calculatevalue2))
                            ResultTextbox.Text = "0"


                    End Select

                Else
                    Select Case button

                        Case "+"
                            _Calculatevalue3 = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDecimal(_Calculatevalue3) + Convert.ToDecimal(_TheFinalResult))
                            ResultTextbox.Text = "0"

                    End Select
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub EqualsButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EqualsButton.Click
        Select Case _CurrentOperator

            Case "+"
                _TheFinalResult = Convert.ToDecimal(_Calculatevalue1) + Convert.ToDecimal(_Calculatevalue2)
                ResultTextbox.Text = _TheFinalResult.ToString
        End Select
        _Calculatevalue1 = Nothing

    End Sub
#End Region
End Class
```

Don't hesitate to remove pieces of the code or change stuff. I can tell that I wrote a whole lot.

Comment: What's the question exactly?  What's not working?  The solution to both of the things you want to accomplish is the same... and it's pretty obvious (you hinted at your self: `previousresult`).

Comment: Hi The problem is that I dont see the clue about how to keep the calculator calculating if the equal sign is not pressed and values keep on comming in, or to keep the calculator calculating if after the equal sign more values are comming in ...

Comment: Save `previousResult`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the priority of operators then the "=" button should'nt do much except for displaying the final result. Calculate the final result on each operator.

final result = 0

If press "+" then add the next number to final result
If press "-" then substract the next number to final result
If press "/" then divide the next number to final result
If press "*" then multiply the next number to final result
If press "=" then display the final result

---

final result = 0
input(8)
add 8 to final result
input(+) input(2)
add 2 to final result
input(=)
display final result

input(/) input(5)
divide 5 to final result
input(=)
display final result

Answer (score 0):

I would keep a running total. If the next input is a mathematical operation (e.g., +,/,*,-), then use the running total as the first operand. However, if it's a number then clear the running total and start a new calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of code to wade thru, but you will likely need a module/form/class level variable which persists outside the various procedures:

```
Public Class SimpleCalculatorForm

 Friend CurrentResult As Integer        ' ??? doesnt look like you care
                                        ' much about datatpes
#Region "FormLoad"
```

Use `currentresult` to store...well, the current result and only clear when the user presses 'C' or the equals sign twice or something like that.  This way the current result will persist  (that is have a `scope`) outside the calc procedures.